# This proof of the uncountability of real numbers is valid?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Some textbooks write down a kind of poof of the uncountability of real numbers, applying the nested interval theorem. Its outline looks as follows:

Consider proving by contradiction. Assume the real number set $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, then we can list all of the numbers like this
$$\mathbb{R}=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n,\cdots\}.$$
First, take a closed interval $[a_1,b_1]$ such that $x_1 \notin [a_1,b_1]$, which is always possible. Now, divide $[a_1,b_1]$ into three equal parts, namely $\left[a_1,\frac{2a_1+b_1}{3}\right],\left[\frac{2a_1+b_1}{3},\frac{a_1+2b_1}{3}\right]$ and $\left[\frac{a_1+2b_1}{3},b_1\right],$ there exists at least one of which not containing $x_2$. Denote it as $[a_2,b_2]$. Then, divide $[a_2,b_2]$ again. Similarily, among the new three, there exists at least one  not containing $x_3$, which is denoted as $[a_3,b_3]$.

Repeat the procedure again and again and infinitely many times. We obtain nested intervals $\{[a_n,b_n]\}$ satisfying that
$$x_n \not\in [a_n,b_n],n=1,2,3\cdots.$$
As per the nested interval theorem, there exists an unique real number $\xi$ belonging to all the intervals $[a_n,b_n]$. In another word, $\xi \neq x_n(n=1,2,3,\cdots)$, which contradicts.

The proof above is valid?

Comment: Yes, this is valid. Do you have a specific concern about the proof?

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: The proof is correct...assuming **all** the rest of "usual assumptions" for $\;\Bbb R\;$, among them the ones that allow us to assume the existence of that interval $\;[a_1,\,b_1]\;$

Comment: This is in fact Cantor's first proof of the uncountability of the reals.

Comment: yes，I can understand it now.